# rewrite rule for shop in lithium / apache

Tags: .htaccess, lithium

I have a lithium installation and all the .htaccess works fine.

I need to install OpenCart as a shopping cart in app/webroot/shop

I copied all the files and also changed the .htaccess file in the root folder of lithium installation as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule    shop/(.*) /app/webroot/shop/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still when I browse http://domain.com/shop it takes me to http://domain.com/app/webroot/shop/

With an error on page:

```
Exception
lithium\action\DispatchException (code 404)
Action `webroot` not found.
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: And what happens when you browse `http://domain.com/shop/` o just `http://domain.com/`, does it go to `http://domain.com/app/webroot/...` without any error?

Comment: When I browse to http://domain.com it browses correctly.

Comment: When I browse to domain.com/somecontroller it also does perfectly.
I just want to add a shop folder in app/webroot/shop so when I do domain.com/shop it should load the files from shop folder

Comment: It would be better if you can point the docroot for your server directly to the app/webroot folder rather than the root folder of lithium.  You might not need any special .htaccess rules then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/webroot/shop/? [NC]
RewriteRule  ^shop/(.*) /app/webroot/shop/$1    [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/webroot/? [NC]
RewriteRule  ^$   /app/webroot/  [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/webroot/? [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /app/webroot/$1     [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: error has changed...

it redirects to http://domain.com/app/webroot/shop/

    Exception

    lithium\action\DispatchException (code 404) 

    Action `webroot` not found.

Comment: Looks the same error message to me, unfortunately. Maybe you want to try with [R,L,NC] flags instead of [L,NC] to see what's going on. Please make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test.

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: The fact is the rule in my answer is indeed redirecting to `domain.com/app/webroot/shop` and so did yours in the question. My rule-set prevents loops and makes sure the last rule is not applied to the previous rewritten URLs, though, but the error 404 is generated by the **substitution URL**, not by the incoming one. So there has to be another reason for the problem. Sorry I can't help with that, I am not familiar with lithium.

Comment: Maybe OpenCart loads a script at `/shop` that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your last "catch all" rule is also redirecting all requests for the shop to lithium, which you don't want.

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all URLs that start with /shop to /app/webroot/shop
RewriteRule  ^shop/.? /app/webroot/shop%{REQUEST_URI}    [L]

# Rewrite all URLs that don't start with /app/webroot/shop to /app/webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/webroot/shop
RewriteRule .? /app/webroot%{REQUEST_URI}     [L]
```